# AngularJS expressions not working in <img-crop>

Tags: angularjs, ng-img-crop

I am trying to modify the project ngImgCrop (https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop) for allowing crop multiple images in the same page, but I do not know how many images I would need, this is created dynamically. So, I need to associate to the 'image' field of  a dynamic value, and at the same time I put this variable in my scope. The problem is that this label is not evaluating the angular code.

```
<div class="cropArea" id="{{'person'+person.Id}}">
    <img-crop image="{{'person'+person.Id}}" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
</div>
```

Even when they have the same code, when the page is loaded the html code shows:

```
<div class="cropArea" id="person12345">
    <img-crop image="{{'person'+person.Id}}" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
</div>
```

In my scope since the beginning the variable $scope.person12345 is created, but It is impossible to make the binding without this part.
What can I do?

Note: 
In my init() function I create all the variables:

```
angular.forEach(persons, function (person, index) {        
    $scope['person'+person.Id]=''; 
});
```

I actually can see the variable $scope.person12345 when the page is loaded. In any case why does the expression worked for the div and not for the img-crop?

Comment: According to the documentation, image should be an assignable angular expression. Show us your controller code. Assuming you have an array of persons, instead of defining $scope.person12345, define `$scope.persons[i].image`, and use, in your ng-repeat iterating on the persons, `image="person.image"`.

Comment: Post all the relevant code in the question, by editing it. Not in comments where that would be unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your expression as a function which will execute in the Controller. string(appending string) will return by a function like below.

```
    <div class="cropArea" id="{{'person'+person.Id}}">
        <img-crop image="getImagePath(person.Id)" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
    </div>

Controller like below:

    $scope.getImagePath = function(id){return 'person'+id+'.png';};
```

Some how there is no parser available in the directive of `image`, that's why you need to give parsed expression via a controller.

Comment: I did it. But even when I saw it enter into the function and returned the right value, while I was debugging, at the end the html was:

`<img-crop image="getImagePath(person.Id)" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>`

I did not put the .png, because this is not the path to the image, It is the name of the variable of the scope binding to this.

Comment: try to return the value of formed variable.
`$scope.getImagePath = function(id){return  $scope['person'+id];};`